# How to Use the WSS Protocol on a Golang Web App hosted on Azure?

Tags: azure, go, websocket, https

**Background:**
I set up a web application using the Azure App Service. The server is written in Golang, and it serves a React client. The client makes a WebSocket connection to the server on load.

**My Question:**

My app is still an early-stage prototype, so it's still part on the azurewebsites.net domain, and I haven't configured my own certificate for it yet (I think Azure provides one by default). How can I make the server accept secure WebSocket messages (WSS protocol) when running on Azure? Normally this would require something like the code below.

```golang
// This worked locally with self-signed certificates. Some code omitted for brevity.
mux := http.NewServeMux()
// ...
mux.HandleFunc("/ws", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        conn, _ := upgrader.Upgrade(w, r, nil)
        // Simple echo server to verify that WebSockets are working.
                // I had more WebSocket code as well, but it's not relevant to the question.
        for {
            messageType, p, err := conn.ReadMessage()
            if err != nil {
                return
            }
            if err := conn.WriteMessage(messageType, p); err != nil {
                return
            }
        }
    })
http.ListenAndServeTLS(":"+port, certPath, keyPath, mux)
```

However, Azure doesn't seem to give the code direct access to the certificates.

**What I've Tried:**

- *Use http.ListenAndServe() instead of http.ListenAndServeTLS()*: Azure automatically redirects HTTP requests to HTTPS. Trying to connect to wss://<app name>.azurewebapps.net from the client fails because the code is still for an HTTP server despite Azure somehow upgrading it to HTTPS. Trying to connect to ws://<app name>.azurewebapps.net from the client causes a DOM_EXCEPTION for trying to make a WS connection from an HTTPS connection.
- *Read an environment variable on the Azure service to find the path to the certificate / key*: None of the environment variables listed from the Azure console looked like they referred to certificates or keys.
- *Upload a self-signed certificate and key to Azure and read them in the http.ListenAndServeTLS() call*: This would not be an ideal solution, and it didn't work either. The browser gave me an error message stating that an HTTP client was trying to connect to an HTTPS server.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that Azure App Services not only upgrades HTTP to HTTPS automatically, but also upgrades WS to WSS automatically. So a solution that worked for me was to use http.listenAndServe, thereby setting up an HTTP / WS server, then have the client hit wss://<app name>.azurewebsites.net. I didn't try it initially because it didn't work locally without modification, but it does work on Azure.